# File shredder with drag and drop batch shredding list and/or scheduler

Tags: file-management, secure

I'm looking for a file shredder where you can drag and drop any number of files and folders to a list of files to shred, and then save that list for later (or regular) shredding.

The tool should be portable or at least not require administrator privileges.

[FreeFileShredder](https://www.fileshredder.org/index.php) would be great, except that unfortunately it doesn't allow to save the list of files to be shredded. I need to save the list for later because the files and folders regularly reappear.

[image: FreeFileShredder]

Comment: This feels like we're missing the "why". How would you save a list of files no longer there? [Note, file shredders are considerably less useful this day & age than they were pre-SSD.] Alternative would be to store them on an encrypted disk image. That's bullet-proof without the password.